# Delete command is not working after choosing OK from Telerik confirm alert

Tags: telerik

I want to use Telerik confirmation alert before deleting record from Telerik grid. Telerik alert is showing but when I choose OK then nothing is happening.

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn  UniqueName="TemplateEditColumn"AllowFiltering="False" AllowSorting="True" HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <ItemTemplate>
         <div class="">
    <asp:ImageButton ID="EditLink"  runat="server"CausesValidation="False" 
      ImageUrl="~/images/edit.png" AlternateText="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" 
     CommandArgument='<%#Eval("AutoID") %>'
     ImageUrl="~/images/Delete.png" AlternateText="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" 
    OnClientClick="radconfirm('Are you sure?', confirmCallBackFn);" />
        </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

here is JS function

```
            function confirmCallBackFn(arg) {
              return false;

          }
```

CodeBehind

```
 protected void RadGrid1_ItemCommand(object sender, GridCommandEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
        {
            Int32 id = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
             //Delete Logic
            lblMessage2.Text = "User has been deleted Successfully.";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
            GetType(),
            "MyKey",
            "refreshGrid();",
            true);


        }


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        AppConfig.Log(ex.Message);  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using `GridTemplateColumn`? You can use the `GridDeleteCommandColumn` or `GridButtonCommandColumn` so that by default it will have the `ConfirmTextFormatString`. so need of javascript functions to handle this.

try this below code :

```
<telerik:GridButtonColumn ButtonType="ImageButton" 
CommandName="Delete" ConfirmTextFormatString="Are you sure to Delete?"  
ConfirmDialogType="classic" HeaderText="Delete" 
UniqueName="DeleteColumn"> </telerik:GridButtonColumn>
```

Just change the column type as above. It will delete the data after **OK** press.

Comment: can't get you, do you want to achieve it in `GridTemplateColumn` ?